# Create a vector of unique values out of several columns with overlapping values

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, unique

In my data.frame I have three columns on the SUBJECT of a row. I want an additional column with a unique subject for each row. First, how my data looks like:

```
DATE <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
COMP <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
RET <- c(-2.0,1.1,3,1.4,-0.2, 0.6, 0.1, -0.21, -1.2, 0.9, 0.3, -0.1,0.3,-0.12)
CLASS <- c("positive", "negative", "aneutral", "positive", "positive", "negative", "aneutral", "positive", "negative", "negative", "positive", "aneutral", "aneutral", "aneutral")
SUBJECT.1 <- c("LITIGATION","LAYOFF","POLLUTION","CHEMICAL DISASTER","PRESS RELEASE","PEOPLE","EMISSIONS","ENERGY","WASTE MANAGEMENT","EMPLOYEES","MANAGEMENT","PRESS RELEASE","HOTELS","POLLUTION")
SUBJECT.2 <- c("POLLUTION","EMPLOYEES","NUCLEAR","FUELS","STOCK OPTION PLAN","EXECUTIVES","CO2","SOLAR","POLLUTION","EXECUTIVES","PRESS RELEASE","CELEBRITIES","CELEBRITIES","LITIGATION")
SUBJECT.3 <- c("ENVIRONMENT","JOB REDUCTIONS","POWER PLANTS","POLLUTION","EMPLOYEES","FRAUD","CLIMATE CHANGE","SUSTAINABILITY","HAZARDOUS WASTE","BONUS PAY","LITIGATION","EMISSIONS","SCANDALS","SCANDALS")
CONTROLVAR <- c("11","13","13","14","13","14","12","11","13","13","14","13","14","12")

mydf <- data.frame(DATE, COMP, RET, CLASS, SUBJECT.1, SUBJECT.2, SUBJECT.3, CONTROLVAR, stringsAsFactors=F)

mydf

#    DATE COMP   RET    CLASS         SUBJECT.1         SUBJECT.2       SUBJECT.3 CONTROLVAR
# 1     1    A -2.00 positive        LITIGATION         POLLUTION     ENVIRONMENT         11
# 2     2    A  1.10 negative            LAYOFF         EMPLOYEES  JOB REDUCTIONS         13
# 3     3    A  3.00 aneutral         POLLUTION           NUCLEAR    POWER PLANTS         13
# 4     4    A  1.40 positive CHEMICAL DISASTER             FUELS       POLLUTION         14
# 5     5    A -0.20 positive     PRESS RELEASE STOCK OPTION PLAN       EMPLOYEES         13
# 6     6    A  0.60 negative            PEOPLE        EXECUTIVES           FRAUD         14
# 7     7    A  0.10 aneutral         EMISSIONS               CO2  CLIMATE CHANGE         12
# 8     1    B -0.21 positive            ENERGY             SOLAR  SUSTAINABILITY         11
# 9     2    B -1.20 negative  WASTE MANAGEMENT         POLLUTION HAZARDOUS WASTE         13
# 10    3    B  0.90 negative         EMPLOYEES        EXECUTIVES       BONUS PAY         13
# 11    4    B  0.30 positive        MANAGEMENT     PRESS RELEASE      LITIGATION         14
# 12    5    B -0.10 aneutral     PRESS RELEASE       CELEBRITIES       EMISSIONS         13
# 13    6    B  0.30 aneutral            HOTELS       CELEBRITIES        SCANDALS         14
# 14    7    B -0.12 aneutral         POLLUTION        LITIGATION        SCANDALS         12
```

Since I want to include the subject as a dummy variable (which should be exclusive) for a later regression, I want a single column SUBJECT with a unique subject for each row. I'd like to focus on the subjects LITIGATION, POLLUTION and LAYOFF.

I want to go from left to right and check each SUBJECT column for LITIGATION, POLLUTION and LAYOFF.

If there is one of the three subjects LITIGATION, POLLUTION or LAYOFF in the first column, this subject is taken. If there is a different subject in the first column, I check the second column and so on. If none of the three subject-columns contain LITIGATION, POLLUTION or LAYOFF, then the subject should be called OTHER.
Also, some of the subjects should be grouped. In this example EMISSIONS should be treated as if it was POLLUTION.

The output should look like this:

```
#    DATE COMP   RET    CLASS         SUBJECT.1         SUBJECT.2       SUBJECT.3    SUBJECT CONTROLVAR
# 1     1    A -2.00 positive        LITIGATION         POLLUTION     ENVIRONMENT LITIGATION         11
# 2     2    A  1.10 negative            LAYOFF         EMPLOYEES  JOB REDUCTIONS     LAYOFF         13
# 3     3    A  3.00 aneutral         POLLUTION           NUCLEAR    POWER PLANTS  POLLUTION         13
# 4     4    A  1.40 positive CHEMICAL DISASTER             FUELS       POLLUTION  POLLUTION         14
# 5     5    A -0.20 positive     PRESS RELEASE STOCK OPTION PLAN       EMPLOYEES      OTHER         13
# 6     6    A  0.60 negative            PEOPLE        EXECUTIVES           FRAUD      OTHER         14
# 7     7    A  0.10 aneutral         EMISSIONS               CO2  CLIMATE CHANGE  POLLUTION         12
# 8     1    B -0.21 positive            ENERGY             SOLAR  SUSTAINABILITY      OTHER         11
# 9     2    B -1.20 negative  WASTE MANAGEMENT         POLLUTION HAZARDOUS WASTE  POLLUTION         13
# 10    3    B  0.90 negative         EMPLOYEES        EXECUTIVES       BONUS PAY      OTHER         13
# 11    4    B  0.30 positive        MANAGEMENT     PRESS RELEASE      LITIGATION LITIGATION         14
# 12    5    B -0.10 aneutral     PRESS RELEASE       CELEBRITIES       EMISSIONS  POLLUTION         13
# 13    6    B  0.30 aneutral            HOTELS       CELEBRITIES        SCANDALS      OTHER         14
# 14    7    B -0.12 aneutral         POLLUTION        LITIGATION        SCANDALS  POLLUTION         12
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydf$SUBJECT <- "OTHER"
sapply(c("SUBJECT.3", "SUBJECT.2", "SUBJECT.1"), function(x) mydf[mydf[, x] %in% c("LITIGATION", "POLLUTION", "LAYOFF", "EMISSIONS"), "SUBJECT"] <<- mydf[mydf[, x] %in% c("LITIGATION", "POLLUTION", "LAYOFF", "EMISSIONS"), x])
mydf$SUBJECT[mydf$SUBJECT == "EMISSIONS"] <- "POLLUTION"
```

Comment: @ David Arenburg: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to group also using only parts of words. Might be a bad example, but let's say i want every value that contains "EMISS", "WAST" and "POLLU" to finally turn into POLLUTION. Is that somehow possible to incorporate into your approach? I'm sure ´grepl()´ does the trick, but don't know exactly how..

Comment: I don't have time now to modify this (at work), I can look later this evening. In the meanwhile take a look at @agstudy answer, he uses regex there

Answer (score 0):

here is a couple of line solution which involves just chaining together 3 `ifelse()`.

`important <- c('LITIGATION','POLLUTION','LAYOFF','EMISSIONS')`

```
ifelse( mydf$SUBJECT.1 %in% important, mydf$SUBJECT.1,
       ifelse( mydf$SUBJECT.2 %in% important, mydf$SUBJECT.2,
             ifelse( mydf$SUBJECT.3 %in% important, mydf$SUBJECT.3,'OTHER')))
```

`mydf$SUBJECT[mydf$SUBJECT=='EMISSIONS'] <- 'POLUTION'`

Comment: it seems that you need to change EMISSIONS to POLLUTION first.

Comment: @BeginneR I change emissions to pollution at the end instead, although admittedly when I added the extra line at the end ( when I saw that cptn wanted to lump pollution with emissions ) I forgot to add it to the `important` vector.