# Create a vector of unique values out of several columns with overlapping values (based on groups of word parts)

Tags: r, vector, character

I asked a very similar question before, but still this is different. Here's the original question:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/24402893/create-a-vector-of-unique-values-out-of-several-columns-with-overlapping-values/24403752?noredirect=1#comment37762312_24403752](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402893/create-a-vector-of-unique-values-out-of-several-columns-with-overlapping-values/24403752?noredirect=1#comment37762312_24403752)

In my data.frame I have three columns on the SUBJECT of a row. I want an additional column with a unique subject for each row. First, how my data looks like:

```
DATE <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
COMP <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
RET <- c(-2.0,1.1,3,1.4,-0.2, 0.6, 0.1, -0.21, -1.2, 0.9, 0.3, -0.1,0.3,-0.12)
CLASS <- c("positive", "negative", "aneutral", "positive", "positive", "negative", "aneutral", "positive", "negative", "negative", "positive", "aneutral", "aneutral", "aneutral")
SUBJECT.1 <- c("LITIGATION","LAYOFF","POLLUTION","CHEMICAL DISASTER","PRESS RELEASE","PEOPLE","EMISSIONS","ENERGY","WASTE MANAGEMENT","EMPLOYEES","MANAGEMENT","PRESS RELEASE","HOTELS","POLLUTION")
SUBJECT.2 <- c("POLLUTION","EMPLOYEES","NUCLEAR","FUELS","STOCK OPTION PLAN","EXECUTIVES","CO2","SOLAR","POLLUTION","EXECUTIVES","PRESS RELEASE","CELEBRITIES","CELEBRITIES","LITIGATION")
SUBJECT.3 <- c("ENVIRONMENT","JOB REDUCTIONS","POWER PLANTS","POLLUTION","EMPLOYEES","FRAUD","CLIMATE CHANGE","SUSTAINABILITY","HAZARDOUS WASTE","BONUS PAY","LITIGATION","EMISSIONS","SCANDALS","SCANDALS")
CONTROLVAR <- c("11","13","13","14","13","14","12","11","13","13","14","13","14","12")

mydf <- data.frame(DATE, COMP, RET, CLASS, SUBJECT.1, SUBJECT.2, SUBJECT.3, CONTROLVAR, stringsAsFactors=F)

mydf

#    DATE COMP   RET    CLASS         SUBJECT.1         SUBJECT.2       SUBJECT.3 CONTROLVAR
# 1     1    A -2.00 positive        LITIGATION         POLLUTION     ENVIRONMENT         11
# 2     2    A  1.10 negative            LAYOFF         EMPLOYEES  JOB REDUCTIONS         13
# 3     3    A  3.00 aneutral         POLLUTION           NUCLEAR    POWER PLANTS         13
# 4     4    A  1.40 positive CHEMICAL DISASTER             FUELS       POLLUTION         14
# 5     5    A -0.20 positive     PRESS RELEASE STOCK OPTION PLAN       EMPLOYEES         13
# 6     6    A  0.60 negative            PEOPLE        EXECUTIVES           FRAUD         14
# 7     7    A  0.10 aneutral         EMISSIONS               CO2  CLIMATE CHANGE         12
# 8     1    B -0.21 positive            ENERGY             SOLAR  SUSTAINABILITY         11
# 9     2    B -1.20 negative  WASTE MANAGEMENT         POLLUTION HAZARDOUS WASTE         13
# 10    3    B  0.90 negative         EMPLOYEES        EXECUTIVES       BONUS PAY         13
# 11    4    B  0.30 positive        MANAGEMENT     PRESS RELEASE      LITIGATION         14
# 12    5    B -0.10 aneutral     PRESS RELEASE       CELEBRITIES       EMISSIONS         13
# 13    6    B  0.30 aneutral            HOTELS       CELEBRITIES        SCANDALS         14
# 14    7    B -0.12 aneutral         POLLUTION        LITIGATION        SCANDALS         12
```

Since I want to include the subject as a dummy variable (which should be exclusive) for a later regression, I want a single column SUBJECT with a unique subject for each row. I'd like to focus on the subjects LITIGATION, POLLUTION and LAYOFF.

I want to go from left to right and check each SUBJECT column for

```
c("LITIGAT", "CLAIM", "SUIT", "JUDG") -> LITIGATION 
c("POLLUT", "WAST", "EMISSION") -> POLLUTION
c("LAYOFF") -> LAYOFF
```

If there is one of the word-parts for LITIGATION, POLLUTION or LAYOFF in the first column, this subject is taken. If there is a different subject in the first column, I check the second column and so on. If none of the three subject-columns contain any word-parts for LITIGATION, POLLUTION or LAYOFF, then the subject should be called OTHER.

The output should look like this:

```
#    DATE COMP   RET    CLASS         SUBJECT.1         SUBJECT.2       SUBJECT.3    SUBJECT CONTROLVAR
# 1     1    A -2.00 positive        LITIGATION         POLLUTION     ENVIRONMENT LITIGATION         11
# 2     2    A  1.10 negative            LAYOFF         EMPLOYEES  JOB REDUCTIONS     LAYOFF         13
# 3     3    A  3.00 aneutral         POLLUTION           NUCLEAR    POWER PLANTS  POLLUTION         13
# 4     4    A  1.40 positive CHEMICAL DISASTER             FUELS       POLLUTION  POLLUTION         14
# 5     5    A -0.20 positive     PRESS RELEASE STOCK OPTION PLAN       EMPLOYEES      OTHER         13
# 6     6    A  0.60 negative            PEOPLE        EXECUTIVES           FRAUD      OTHER         14
# 7     7    A  0.10 aneutral         EMISSIONS               CO2  CLIMATE CHANGE  POLLUTION         12
# 8     1    B -0.21 positive            ENERGY             SOLAR  SUSTAINABILITY      OTHER         11
# 9     2    B -1.20 negative  WASTE MANAGEMENT         POLLUTION HAZARDOUS WASTE  POLLUTION         13
# 10    3    B  0.90 negative         EMPLOYEES        EXECUTIVES       BONUS PAY      OTHER         13
# 11    4    B  0.30 positive        MANAGEMENT     PRESS RELEASE      LITIGATION LITIGATION         14
# 12    5    B -0.10 aneutral     PRESS RELEASE       CELEBRITIES       EMISSIONS  POLLUTION         13
# 13    6    B  0.30 aneutral            HOTELS       CELEBRITIES        SCANDALS      OTHER         14
# 14    7    B -0.12 aneutral         POLLUTION        LITIGATION        SCANDALS  POLLUTION         12
```

Comment: If your other question is very similar, why not post a link to it? Might be helpful in answering this one.

Comment: I undelete my answer in the other question. Maybe it helps. It uses regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dat <- stack(sapply(c("LITIGATION", "POLLUTION", "LAYOFF"),
               function(x) grep(paste(get(x),collapse="|"),
                       as.character(interaction(mydf[,5:7],sep=" ")))))
 dat2 <- merge(dat, data.frame(values=1:14),all=TRUE)

dat2N <- dat2[!duplicated(dat2$values),] ##delete duplicated values
dat2N$ind <- as.character(dat2N$ind) 
dat2N$ind[is.na(dat2N$ind)] <- "OTHER"  ##change NAs to "OTHER"
transform(mydf, SUBJECT=dat2N$ind)
```

## Explanation

You already created three vectors: (pasting your code)

```
c("LITIGAT", "CLAIM", "SUIT", "JUDG") -> LITIGATION 
c("POLLUT", "WAST", "EMISSION") -> POLLUTION
c("LAYOFF") -> LAYOFF
```

So, running the below code gives:

```
 lapply(c("LITIGATION","POLLUTION", "LAYOFF"), function(x) get(x)) #get search by name for an object
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "LITIGAT" "CLAIM"   "SUIT"    "JUDG"   

 #[[2]]
 #[1] "POLLUT"   "WAST"     "EMISSION"

 #[[3]]
 #[1] "LAYOFF"
```

Then I pasted the components to make a single string separated by "|" for `grep`

```
 sapply(c("LITIGATION","POLLUTION", "LAYOFF"), function(x) paste(get(x),collapse="|"))
#           LITIGATION                 POLLUTION                    LAYOFF 
#"LITIGAT|CLAIM|SUIT|JUDG"    "POLLUT|WAST|EMISSION"                  "LAYOFF" 

as.character(interaction(mydf[,5:7],sep=" ")) #pasted the concerned columns rowwise
#[1] "LITIGATION POLLUTION ENVIRONMENT"          
#[2] "LAYOFF EMPLOYEES JOB REDUCTIONS"           
#[3] "POLLUTION NUCLEAR POWER PLANTS"            
#[4] "CHEMICAL DISASTER FUELS POLLUTION"         
#[5] "PRESS RELEASE STOCK OPTION PLAN EMPLOYEES"
```

and search for the pattern in the combined rows using grep

I used `stack` to get the row index along with object names ie. LITIGATION, POLLUTION.  Then I merged the dataset with rownumbers.  You can also use ?match.  As there were multiple values that mapped to different objects, the first one was selected and rest deleted using `duplicated.  Changed the`ind`column from`factor`to`character`and the`ind` that were NAs were changed to "OTHER".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try as soon as I have access to R. I don't see any of the word parts (e.g. "LITIGAT", "POLLUT", "WAST") in your code. Could you explain what your function does?

Comment: hey akrun. Your approach works for this example. Do you also know a more efficient way? My original data.frame contains ~30000 rows and unfortunately, there's a memory size error..